# Is it possible to perform another read in the middle of stdin.lines()?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following code:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead, Read};

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();

    let mut content_length = 0;
    for line_wrapped in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line_wrapped.unwrap();
        if line == "" {
            let mut buf = vec![0u8; content_length];
            stdin.read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();
            print!("{:?}", buf);
        }
        if line.starts_with("Content-Length: ") {
            content_length = line
                .split("Content-Length: ")
                .nth(1)
                .unwrap()
                .parse()
                .unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

And the compiler output:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `stdin` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
7  |     for line_wrapped in stdin.lock().lines() {
   |                         ----- immutable borrow occurs here
...
11 |             stdin.read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

Is there a way I could fix the error while keeping a similar structure of the program (read within a `.lines()`)?

Comment: If stdin contains `\n\nhello\nworld\n` and `content_length` is 10, should `buf` contain `hello\nworl` and `line` contain `d` in the next iteration? Or do you want to stop processing lines (break out of the loop) after reading the first empty line?

Comment: @trentcl I think that in this case I would expect it to read 10 bytes after first empty line, which would mean that the string would start with `\nhello`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something like `"Content-Length: 10\n\nhello\nworld\n"`. But I'm wondering what your plan is for the trailing bytes; do they have to show up in the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: yes, that's what I would expect as after Content-Length there should be another WARC object.

Answer (score 2):

Alternating between buffered and non-buffered reads of the same stream can be quite tricky. If you didn't have to `lock` standard input in order to call `lines()`, the internal buffer used to implement `StdinLock` could consume beyond the `\n` of the empty line, and the subsequent `read_exact` call would not start at the right place.

So you have to `lock` it only once, and you have to call `read_exact` on the same buffered reader that gave you the `Lines`, to be sure no bytes are lost. At first glance this looks impossible: `lines()` takes `self` by value, so once you've called it, you can't call `read_exact` on the same object. But there's a bit of a trick you can use.

The documentation for `BufRead` [contains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#implementors) this blanket `impl`:

```
impl<'a, B: BufRead + ?Sized> BufRead for &'a mut B
```

`&mut` references to things that implement `BufRead` *also* implement `BufRead`. So you can take a temporary `&mut` reference of your `StdinLock`, call `lines()` on *that*, discard the `Lines` in time to `read_exact` the payload into `buf`, and then start over again with another `&mut` reference and another `Lines`.

This approach necessitates adding another loop, with a flag `has_header` to indicate whether to break the outer loop. It's not very pretty, but maybe you can work with it.

```
let stdin = io::stdin();
let mut stdin_buf = stdin.lock();

'record: loop {
    let mut content_length = 0;
    let mut has_header = false;
    'header: for line_wrapped in (&mut stdin_buf).lines() {
        let line = line_wrapped.unwrap();
        if line.starts_with("Content-Length: ") {
            content_length = line["Content-Length: ".len()..].parse().unwrap();
        }
        if line.is_empty() {
            has_header = true;
            break 'header;
        }
    }
    if has_header {
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; content_length];
        stdin_buf.read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", buf);
    } else {
        break 'record;
    }
}
```

A final note: It's unclear what should happen when the `Content-Length` header is absent. If your original code worked, it would reuse the previously defined value (whatever the last content length was, or 0 for the first record). My version just uses 0 all the time. It's idiomatic in Rust to use `Option` to represent possibly-uninitialized values such as `content_length`, so initializing it to `None` could be a better option if the absence of a `Content-Length` header is an error that needs to be detected.